# get previous image in array

Tags: angular, function, button

picture-table.component.ts

```
  showPicture(picture: AccessApictures){
     console.log(picture.filename);

let pictureDialog = this.dialog.open(PictureModalComponent, 
  { data: {
      id: picture.id,
      caption: picture.caption,
      url: picture.filename,
      servDate: picture.servDate,
      servNum: picture.aservrecno,
    }
  }
);  
}

  onPreviousClick(id: number, index: number, picture: AccessApictures) {


for (let id in this.pictures){
  return [index -= 1];
}
```

picture-modal.html

```
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>Service date: {{model.servDate}} 
      <br>
    Service number: {{model.servNum}}</h1>
     <div mat-dialog-content>
      <img class="img" src= {{model.url}}/>
    <p><strong>Caption:</strong> {{model.caption}}</p>
   </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)='onPreviousClick()'>Previous </button>
  <button mat-button (click)='onNextClick()'>Next</button>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
    </div>
```

I edited my question. I am trying to make the previous button on my html go to the previous image in my array

Comment: Please note that you cannot call `console.log`, or any other global function, in the HTML template.

Comment: i was calling it in type script

Comment: can you please add the context in which onPreviousClick is defined?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Make sure that `onPreviousClick` is defined in the component class of the template where it is called. I see `picture-table.component.ts` and `picture-modal.html` in your question.

Comment: yeah it is. i imported the pictureModalComponent

Comment: I mean: it must be a method of the `picture-modal` component. If it is defined in `picture-table`, you have to wrap it in a method of `picture-modal`. Importing the other component is not enough to make available in the template.

Comment: okay that is working now but how can i get the previous index

Comment: @MelissaChillington why do you have a return in a for loop? it is going to do the first iteration and then return from the function. And in your html you have `onPreviousClick()` but in your ts you have `onPreviousClick(id, index)`. The code needs to be cleaned up a little more

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the 2 parameters ( id & index ) onPreviousClick is expecting.

that would be

```
<button mat-button (click) ='onPreviousClick(1,1)'>Previous </button>
```

or what ever id and index are

Comment: yeah but even if i just try and console.log('hello') it'll tell me its not a function

Comment: who tells you that? IDE, or when you run `ng serve` or when you do `ng build --prod`?

Comment: spaces are the problem, it is (click)='onPreviousClick(1,1)' please check example 13 on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu component is button-function

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature is wrong.

If you don't want to pass any values to it then you should provide default values like so:

```
onPreviousClick(id = 0, index = 0) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

Note that you don't need to define the type since TypeScript will infer type number given that the default value is 0.